# Dividing by Zero?! - Datareader OleDB VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I have a problem with the following:

```
                Dim sql As String = "SELECT ArithmeticScore FROM " & tablename & " WHERE DateAscending = " & todaysdate.ToString("%dd/mm/yyyy")
                Using connection As New OleDbConnection(getconn)
                    Dim findscore As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
                    connection.Open()
                    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = findscore.ExecuteReader() 'ERROR OCCURS HERE
                    While reader.Read()
                        If Not reader.IsDBNull(0) Then
                            scoreexists = True
                            MsgBox("score exists")
                        Else
                            scoreexists = False
                            MsgBox("score does not exist")
                        End If
                    End While
                    reader.Close()
                    connection.Close()
                End Using
```

I want to check if the cell in `ArithmeticScore` is empty when `DateAscending = todaysdate`

`getconn` Holds the connection string, `tablename` holds the name of the table.

I'm getting the error: 'Division by zero'

I understand why the program can't do that, but why on earth would it? I'm only trying to find out if a cell has a value in it or if its empty. The cell in question does have a value, `51.606` as a `Decimal`. I'm using an access database.

Comment: Use parameterized queries. You're passing a date as an interpolated string (`WHERE DateAscending = 01/05/2020`, or rather `11/14/2020` with your formatting string), which is not how date literals are passed in Access (or any database server for that matter). To avoid such issues, pass a typed parameter (`WHERE DateAscending = ?`, `findscore.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = todaysdate` -- note, no formatting required). This is assuming the Access DB is using a date/time column and not a string itself.

Comment: The database is of a date/time format. I changed the first line to: `Dim sql As String = "SELECT ArithmeticScore FROM " & tablename & " WHERE DateAscending = @todaysdate"`. After which line do I place `findscore.Parameters.Add("@todaysdate", OleDbType.Date).Value = todaysdate`?

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from Jeroen's comment, the division by zero error is being triggered by the date string (/05 is interpreted as /0 not /5)

Comment: Put it straight after Dim findscore

Comment: As an aside, assuming there is only one result per date, you really should use ExecuteScalar rather than ExecuteReader.

Comment: Thanks very much, all works fine now and i get why the error occurred in the first place

Comment: If you solved your own problem with the help of comments then the intention of this site is that you post an answer to your own question. This site is to help everyone, not just the person asking the question. If your problem is solved but there's no accepted answer for your question, you're not using the site correctly. Please post your solution as an answer and accept it. I'm not 100% sure that you don't need to pass a minimum number of reputation points to do that but do it if you can.